# Extracting specific elements from a list of strings and creating a new list?

Tags: python, list

I am a beginner in python.

This my issue. I have a list as below

```
lst = ['UGAGGUAGUAGGUUGUAUAGUU', 'CUAUGCAAUUUUCUACCUUACC', 'UCCCUGAGACCUCAAGUGUGA',
       'ACACCUGGGCUCUCCGGGUACC', 'CAUACUUCCUUACAUGCCCAUA', 'UGGAAUGUAAAGAAGUAUGUA',
       'CAUCAAAGCGGUGGUUGAUGUG', 'UAUCACAGCCAGCUUUGAUGUGC', 'AGGCAGUGUGGUUAGCUGGUUG',
       'ACGGCUACCUUCACUGCCACCC']
```

Now I need to extract the first letter from all the 10 elements in the `lst` and then put them in a new list. similarly second letter, third letter and so forth until the last letter is extracted from all the ten elements and append it to the new list. The output has to look like this

```
new_lst = ['UCUACUCUAA', 'GUCCAGAAGC', 'AACAUGUUGG', 'GUCCAACCCG', 'GGUCCAAAAC',
           'UCGUUUACGU', 'AAAGUGAAUA', 'GAGGCUGGGC', 'UUAGCACCUC', 'AUCCUAGCGU', ..., 'C']
```

I tried this code:

```
new_lst = []
new_lst.append(''.join([x[i] for x in lst]))
```

The above code prints only the first 10 elements in the new_list because the index is from 0 to 9 (I misunderstood what index means).

Then I did the following

```
final= []
for j in range(1,len(lst),1):
 new_lst = []
 for x in lst:
   c = len(x)
    for i in range(1,c,1):
       while (i<len(x)):
          new_lst.append(x[i])
       else:
          new_lst.append("")
 final.append([new_lst])
print final
```

When I execute this code, it throws a memory error. The reason why I checked the length is because the elements in the `lst` are not of the same length and when I was using a different code it threw an error, `IndexError: string index out of range`.

I first wanted to dissect the code, so I just used the following code:

```
lst2 = []
for x in lst:
 c = len (x)
 print c
  for i in range(0,c,1):
    print i,
    print x[i],
```

I got the following output:

```
22
0 U 1 G 2 A 3 G 4 G 5 U 6 A 7 G 8 U 9 A 10 G 11 G 12 U 13 U 14 G 15 U 16       A 17 U 18 A 19 G 20 U 21 U 22
0 C 1 U 2 A 3 U 4 G 5 C 6 A 7 A 8 U 9 U 10 U 11 U 12 C 13 U 14 A 15 C 16  C 17 U 18 U 19 A 20 C 21 C 21
0 U 1 C 2 C 3 C 4 U 5 G 6 A 7 G 8 A 9 C 10 C 11 U 12 C 13 A 14 A 15 G 16 U 17 G 18 U 19 G 20 A 22
0 A 1 C 2 A 3 C 4 C 5 U 6 G 7 G 8 G 9 C 10 U 11 C 12 U 13 C 14 C 15 G 16 G 17 G 18 U 19 A 20 C 21 C 22
0 C 1 A 2 U 3 A 4 C 5 U 6 U 7 C 8 C 9 U 10 U 11 A 12 C 13 A 14 U 15 G 16 C 17 C 18 C 19 A 20 U 21 A 21
0 U 1 G 2 G 3 A 4 A 5 U 6 G 7 U 8 A 9 A 10 A 11 G 12 A 13 A 14 G 15 U 16 A 17 U 18 G 19 U 20 A 22
0 C 1 A 2 U 3 C 4 A 5 A 6 A 7 G 8 C 9 G 10 G 11 U 12 G 13 G 14 U 15 U 16 G 17 A 18 U 19 G 20 U 21 G 23
0 U 1 A 2 U 3 C 4 A 5 C 6 A 7 G 8 C 9 C 10 A 11 G 12 C 13 U 14 U 15 U 16 G 17 A 18 U 19 G 20 U 21 G 22 C 22
0 A 1 G 2 G 3 C 4 A 5 G 6 U 7 G 8 U 9 G 10 G 11 U 12 U 13 A 14 G 15 C 16 U 17 G 18 G 19 U 20 U 21 G 22
0 A 1 C 2 G 3 G 4 C 5 U 6 A 7 C 8 C 9 U 10 U 11 C 12 A 13 C 14 U 15 G 16 C 17 C 18 A 19 C 20 C 21 C
```

As you can see above the loop goes through the first element, but after extracting the first character from the first element in `lst`, it goes to the second character in the first element. But I wanted the loop to go through the second element in the list `lst`. Also, there are elements in the list with unequal lengths, so wondering if there is a way to avoid the `IndexError: string index out of range`?

I guess I am missing something, it might be too silly. sorry for being naive. If you could please suggest different methods to accomplish the job, it would be awesome. I checked online about using array from the module numpy, but is there a way to do this without numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
import itertools
[''.join(chars) for chars in itertools.zip_longest(*lst,fillvalue = '')]
```

output:

```
['UCUACUCUAA', 'GUCCAGAAGC', 'AACAUGUUGG', 'GUCCAACCCG', 'GGUCCAAAAC', 'UCGUUUACGU', 'AAAGUGAAUA', 'GAGGCUGGGC', 'UUAGCACCUC', 'AUCCUAGCGU', 'GUCUUAGAGU', 'GUUCAGUGUC', 'UCCUCAGCUA', 'UUACAAGUAC', 'GAACUGUUGU', 'UCGGGUUUCG', 'ACUGCAGGUC', 'UUGGCUAAGC', 'AUUUCGUUGA', 'GAGAAUGGUC', 'UCACUAUUUC', 'UCCAGGGC', 'C']
```

The built-in `zip()` and well as the `itertools` method `zip_longest()` in Python 3 (or, in Python 2, the `itertools` methods `izip()` and `izip_longest()`) are the tools of choice when you want to process two or more iterables (such as lists, strings, or generators) in parallel. To see the difference between `zip()` and `zip_longest()` consider the following:

```
for chars in zip('ABCD','EFG','HI'):
    print(chars)
print('')
for chars in itertools.zip_longest('ABCD','EFG','HI',fillvalue = ''):
    print(chars)
```

Output:

```
('A', 'E', 'H')
('B', 'F', 'I')

('A', 'E', 'H')
('B', 'F', 'I')
('C', 'G', '')
('D', '', '')
```

the first tuple produced is the tuple of the first elements, the second tuple produced is the tuple of the second elements, etc. `zip` (or `izip`) stops as soon as the first iterable is exhausted. In this case it can't return a tuple of the third character in each string since the 3rd input to `zip` lacks a third character. `zip_longest()` (or `izip_longest()`) allows for a fillvalue to take the place of missing items in the shorter iterables once they are exahausted. Here I used the empty string since that disappears when the tuples are joined by `''`.

In the above code I hardwired in 3 strings to `zip_longest()`. For your problem, you would have to explicitly enter 10 inputs, which would be tedious in the extreme, or use the *unpacking operator* `*`. If I have a list:

```
strings = ['ABCD','EFG', 'HI']
```

Then

```
for char in itertools.zip_longest(*strings, fillvalue = ''):
```

is *equivalent* to

```
for chars in itertools.zip_longest('ABCD','EFG','HI',fillvalue = ''):
```

Comment: Darn. Beat me to it!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sometimes Python is so easy it almost seems like cheating.

Comment: It's a problem when I need to use other languages and my mind immediately goes to "well, in Python I could just use `itertools` and..."

Comment: @JohnColeman: Thank you very much. John could you please explain what each part in your command does. I know the outer square bracket means that it is a list, ''.join(chars) means we are joining all the elements in chars by ''. But i am not quite sure what "for chars in itertools.zip_longest(*lst,fillvalue = '')" does. I am just asking this for my own learning experience. Also in itertools.zip didn't work for me. it showed an error, but itertools.izip worked

Comment: In Python 2 `itertools.zip_longest()` is `itertools.izip_longest()`. You do want the `longest` part.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iterate through indices of the longest string:

```
lst = ['UGAGGUAGUAGGUUGUAUAGUU', 'CUAUGCAAUUUUCUACCUUACC',
       'UCCCUGAGACCUCAAGUGUGA', 'ACACCUGGGCUCUCCGGGUACC',
       'CAUACUUCCUUACAUGCCCAUA', 'UGGAAUGUAAAGAAGUAUGUA', 
       'CAUCAAAGCGGUGGUUGAUGUG', 'UAUCACAGCCAGCUUUGAUGUGC',
       'AGGCAGUGUGGUUAGCUGGUUG', 'ACGGCUACCUUCACUGCCACCC']

max_len = max(len(x) for x in lst) # length of the longest string
new_lst = [ ''.join(x[i] for x in lst if i < len(x)) for i in range(max_len)]
```

Comment: Thank you Yevhen :)